# error: expected a type - eventDispatcher:(nonnull RCTEventDispatcher *)eventDispatcher; AND 'Undefined symbol' errors during iOS build

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

Cannot build iOS app after upgrading from RN version 0.63.2 to 0.65.0-rc.3. I am getting this error:

> In file included from /Users/.../ReactNativeProjects/.../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/RNGestureHandlerManager.m:1:
> /Users/.../ReactNativeProjects/.../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/RNGestureHandlerManager.h:9:52: error: expected a type
> eventDispatcher:(nonnull RCTEventDispatcher *)eventDispatcher;

Problem is in RNGestureHandlerManager.h, on the line below:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithUIManager:(nonnull RCTUIManager *)uiManager
                          eventDispatcher:(nonnull RCTEventDispatcher *)eventDispatcher;
```

[image]

When I upgrade to RNGestureHandler version 1.10.3 I get the errors below:

> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTScrollView
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_METACLASS*$_RCTViewManager
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTEventEmitter
>
> Undefined symbol: __RCTNotImplementedException
>
> Undefined symbol: _RCTGetUIManagerQueue
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTConvert
>
> Undefined symbol: _RCTRegisterModule
>
> Undefined symbol: _RCTDefaultLogFunction
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTRootView
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_METACLASS*$_RCTEventEmitter
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTTouchHandler
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_RCTViewManager
>
> Undefined symbol: __RCTLogNativeInternal

It has been 3 days since I submitted the issue on the github page but no response from the team. I would really appreciate any help. Any ideas are welcome! This has really started to bother me.

Here is a link to the issue I created on github: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1543

Thanks a lot...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Alright. After a couple of days of reading/digging and trying many different solutions this is how I fixed it.

1- Added the import statement below in `RNGestureHandlerManager.h`

```
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
```

When I tried to re-build the app, this created the same `Undefined symbol` errors as if I had updated the RNGestureHandler version to 1.10.3 (see the red error messages in the question).

2- Here is the critical part.

I checked "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH" setting under `Build Settings` of the main project target. It was 'YES' for both debug and release modes.

[image]

Then I checked the same settings for `RNGestureHandler` package inside the `Pods` project. In my case, it was YES for debug and NO for release. I was trying to build the app in Release mode so I changed this setting to YES for release mode for the `RNGestureHandler` package.

Then I tried building my app again. This time the `Undefined symbol` errors for the RNGestureHandler package were gone. Similar messages started to show up for other packages. I did the same settings update for all the packages that created these `Undefined symbol` errors and finally, my app was built successfully in release mode! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-gesture-handled lib was upgraded and the fix is included, so upgrading the library will fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29890405)

Comment: ... you clearly didn't understand my reply which was an answer.... although I've referred to the post above...

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in a newer version of the lib.

In your `package.json` file, change the version of the `react-native-gesture-handler` lib to `~2.5.0` or higher. Then run `yarn` or `npm i`, followed by `cd ios && pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various ways of cleaning and reinstalling as well as deleting Xcode derived data and nothing worked. What fixed it for me was...

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
```

See related issue: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/179